# How to enable JSP remote debugging in MyEclipse?

Tags: jsp, remote-debugging

We have trying to debug JSP file which is running on Weblogic server remotely. We have tried the different options for enabling JSP debugging, but, couldn't able to achieve.Could anyone tell me how can we do that?

Comment: Do you have the aceess to webapps foder for that server?

Comment: yes, I do have the access.

Comment: you can try using filezilla or from command prompt to open that perticular jsp by listing the pages availble

Comment: am sorry, I want to debug from MyEclipse where my JSPs are having java code using scriptlets.

Comment: where is ur code On serveror local machine ?you are not clear about ur question

Comment: code is not on server, but server and code both in local.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug a JSP page easily just like a java code:
"a JSP file is the same like debugging a Java class, but the most
features (Watch, Inspect, etc) are not implemented. The only way to
get the values of variables is the Variables view."
See the link below:
https://www.laliluna.de/articles/posts/debugging-jsp-java-tutorial.html